# How to detect overfitting in xgboost(from test-auc score)

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost, auc

I am trying to understand how to build predictive models and recently came across xgboost package in R and tried to implement it using Titanic dataset. I built a model and now I am wondering how to detect that if my model is overfitting or not and how many rounds to choose and if this is based on train-error or test-error.

This is the code:

```
#Load Dataset
titanic.train <- read.csv("D:/Data/titanic/train.csv")
titanic.test <- read.csv("D:/Data/titanic/test.csv")
PassengerId=titanic.test$PassengerId
head(titanic.train)

#Create columns to distinguish between Train and Test datasets
titanic.train$IsTrainSet <- TRUE
titanic.test$IsTrainSet <- FALSE

#Create a missing column for Test data
titanic.test$Survived <- NA

#Combine Test and Train Datasets
titanic.full <- rbind(titanic.train , titanic.test)
tail(titanic.full)

titanic.full$Name <- as.character(titanic.full$Name)

titanic.full$Title <- sapply(titanic.full$Name, FUN=function(x) {strsplit(x, split='[,.]')[[1]][2]})
titanic.full$Title <- sub(' ','',titanic.full$Title)

titanic.full$Title[titanic.full$Title %in% c('Capt', 'Col' , 'Dr' , 'Don', 'Major', 'Sir' , 'Rev' ,
                                             'Dona', 'Lady', 'the Countess' , 'Jonkheer', 'Master')] <- 'Noble'


titanic.full$Title[titanic.full$Title %in% c('Ms', 'Miss' , 'Mlle')] <- 'Miss'
titanic.full$Title[titanic.full$Title %in% c('Mrs' , 'Mme')] <- 'Mrs'
table(titanic.full$Title) 

#Family size 3 and greater are TRUE or 1
titanic.full$Family <- titanic.full$SibSp + titanic.full$Parch + 1
table(titanic.full$Family)
#titanic.full$Family <- titanic.full$Family >= 3
#titanic.full$Family <- as.factor(titanic.full$Family)
#levels(titanic.full$Family) <- c(0,1)
#titanic.full$Family


titanic.full <- titanic.full[c( "Pclass" , "Title" , "Sex" , "Age" , "Family"  , "Fare", "SibSp" , "Parch"  , "Embarked"  , "Survived")]
head(titanic.full)




#Categorical Casting
titanic.full$Title <- as.factor(titanic.full$Title)
titanic.full$Sex <- as.factor(titanic.full$Sex)
titanic.full$Embarked <- as.factor(titanic.full$Embarked)


titanicDummy <- dummyVars("~.",data=titanic.full, fullRank=T)
titanic.full <- as.data.frame(predict(titanicDummy,titanic.full))
print(names(titanic.full))



#Create test and train data sets
titanic.train <- titanic.full[1:891,]
titanic.test <- titanic.full[892:1309,]

#XGBoosting

set.seed(35)
labs <- titanic.train$Survived
names(titanic.full)
dat <- titanic.train[c("Pclass","Title.Mr","Title.Mrs","Title.Noble", "Sex.male","Age", "Family", "Fare", "SibSp","Parch","Embarked.C","Embarked.Q","Embarked.S")]
titdata <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(dat), missing = NA, label=as.numeric(labs))
res <- xgb.cv(objective="binary:logistic" , eta=0.1, metric="auc", max_depth = 3,
              data = titdata , label=as.numeric(labs) , nrounds =   200 , nfold = 10 , prediction = TRUE)
```

This is the result and I need help interpreting it and some advice on what should I look at to increase or decrease "eta" and "max_depth"

> > res <- xgb.cv(objective="binary:logistic" , eta=0.1, metric="auc", max_depth = 3,
> >     +               data = titdata , label=as.numeric(labs) , nrounds =   200 , nfold = 10 , prediction = TRUE)
> >     [1]   train-auc:0.869192+0.009120 test-auc:0.856596+0.056215 
> >     [2]   train-auc:0.875578+0.007362 test-auc:0.864648+0.059435 
> >     [3]   train-auc:0.877447+0.006179 test-auc:0.865721+0.059722 
> >     [4]   train-auc:0.881547+0.006015 test-auc:0.867861+0.060918 
> >     [5]   train-auc:0.882322+0.006134 test-auc:0.869224+0.060917 
> >     [6]   train-auc:0.884335+0.005501 test-auc:0.871305+0.061070 
> >     [7]   train-auc:0.885292+0.004622 test-auc:0.871798+0.060813 
> >     [8]   train-auc:0.886477+0.004309 test-auc:0.872152+0.060549 
> >     [9]   train-auc:0.887559+0.004344 test-auc:0.870026+0.060668 
> >     [10]  train-auc:0.889544+0.004236 test-auc:0.866687+0.062255 
> >     [11]  train-auc:0.890486+0.004868 test-auc:0.868404+0.060674 
> >     [12]  train-auc:0.891533+0.004522 test-auc:0.866567+0.060826 
> >     [13]  train-auc:0.893234+0.004674 test-auc:0.865659+0.060419 
> >     [14]  train-auc:0.894624+0.004733 test-auc:0.866490+0.061235 
> >     [15]  train-auc:0.895527+0.004583 test-auc:0.867123+0.060497 
> >     [16]  train-auc:0.896230+0.005107 test-auc:0.866917+0.061243 
> >     [17]  train-auc:0.897409+0.004722 test-auc:0.868524+0.058841 
> >     [18]  train-auc:0.898608+0.005050 test-auc:0.866894+0.059343 
> >     [19]  train-auc:0.899822+0.005369 test-auc:0.868109+0.055177 
> >     [20]  train-auc:0.900747+0.004902 test-auc:0.869309+0.055201 
> >     [21]  train-auc:0.901191+0.005089 test-auc:0.869443+0.054093 
> >     [22]  train-auc:0.901958+0.005586 test-auc:0.871578+0.050996 
> >     [23]  train-auc:0.902394+0.005318 test-auc:0.871743+0.050770 
> >     [24]  train-auc:0.902980+0.005217 test-auc:0.872139+0.050897 
> >     [25]  train-auc:0.903442+0.004909 test-auc:0.871261+0.052185 
> >     [26]  train-auc:0.904110+0.004886 test-auc:0.869618+0.051097 
> >     [27]  train-auc:0.905216+0.004741 test-auc:0.868398+0.051865 
> >     [28]  train-auc:0.906057+0.004625 test-auc:0.868029+0.052551 
> >     [29]  train-auc:0.906668+0.004490 test-auc:0.868944+0.052679 
> >     [30]  train-auc:0.907469+0.004247 test-auc:0.867783+0.052927 
> >     [31]  train-auc:0.908050+0.004229 test-auc:0.866851+0.053204 
> >     [32]  train-auc:0.909257+0.004118 test-auc:0.866138+0.055716 
> >     [33]  train-auc:0.909878+0.004200 test-auc:0.866495+0.055579 
> >     [34]  train-auc:0.910485+0.004335 test-auc:0.867096+0.055105 
> >     [35]  train-auc:0.911178+0.004286 test-auc:0.866654+0.055277 
> >     [36]  train-auc:0.912293+0.004265 test-auc:0.866994+0.055417 
> >     [37]  train-auc:0.913109+0.003980 test-auc:0.866273+0.054600 
> >     [38]  train-auc:0.913829+0.004026 test-auc:0.866423+0.055104 
> >     [39]  train-auc:0.914379+0.004208 test-auc:0.866457+0.054575 
> >     [40]  train-auc:0.914986+0.004381 test-auc:0.865801+0.055015 
> >     [41]  train-auc:0.915569+0.004222 test-auc:0.866209+0.054269 
> >     [42]  train-auc:0.916022+0.004439 test-auc:0.864052+0.057692 
> >     [43]  train-auc:0.916491+0.004346 test-auc:0.864199+0.058291 
> >     [44]  train-auc:0.916902+0.004508 test-auc:0.864829+0.058214 
> >     [45]  train-auc:0.917351+0.004464 test-auc:0.863823+0.058295 
> >     [46]  train-auc:0.917825+0.004461 test-auc:0.863831+0.058384 
> >     [47]  train-auc:0.918281+0.004501 test-auc:0.863642+0.058678 
> >     [48]  train-auc:0.918833+0.004514 test-auc:0.863539+0.058620 
> >     [49]  train-auc:0.919144+0.004550 test-auc:0.863587+0.058575 
> >     [50]  train-auc:0.919679+0.004454 test-auc:0.864577+0.057084 
> >     [51]  train-auc:0.920047+0.004557 test-auc:0.864855+0.057393 
> >     [52]  train-auc:0.920453+0.004770 test-auc:0.865826+0.055897 
> >     [53]  train-auc:0.920900+0.004533 test-auc:0.865653+0.055794 
> >     [54]  train-auc:0.921269+0.004572 test-auc:0.865483+0.055574 
> >     [55]  train-auc:0.921690+0.004696 test-auc:0.866402+0.054969 
> >     [56]  train-auc:0.922165+0.004787 test-auc:0.867068+0.054520 
> >     [57]  train-auc:0.922492+0.004574 test-auc:0.866784+0.054629 
> >     [58]  train-auc:0.922904+0.004615 test-auc:0.866632+0.054462 
> >     [59]  train-auc:0.923430+0.004563 test-auc:0.866625+0.054274 
> >     [60]  train-auc:0.923674+0.004492 test-auc:0.866584+0.054400 
> >     [61]  train-auc:0.923847+0.004484 test-auc:0.866553+0.054280 
> >     [62]  train-auc:0.924204+0.004409 test-auc:0.867392+0.053863 
> >     [63]  train-auc:0.924350+0.004435 test-auc:0.867171+0.053805 
> >     [64]  train-auc:0.924681+0.004547 test-auc:0.867443+0.053727 
> >     [65]  train-auc:0.925087+0.004428 test-auc:0.867295+0.053986 
> >     [66]  train-auc:0.925663+0.004398 test-auc:0.866947+0.054199 
> >     [67]  train-auc:0.925823+0.004476 test-auc:0.867209+0.053866 
> >     [68]  train-auc:0.926276+0.004367 test-auc:0.867635+0.054284 
> >     [69]  train-auc:0.926702+0.004346 test-auc:0.867142+0.054288 
> >     [70]  train-auc:0.927134+0.004529 test-auc:0.867386+0.054673 
> >     [71]  train-auc:0.927491+0.004571 test-auc:0.866602+0.054073 
> >     [72]  train-auc:0.928026+0.004551 test-auc:0.866468+0.054223 
> >     [73]  train-auc:0.928421+0.004448 test-auc:0.866837+0.054042 
> >     [74]  train-auc:0.928793+0.004538 test-auc:0.866865+0.053660 
> >     [75]  train-auc:0.928996+0.004604 test-auc:0.866813+0.053500 
> >     [76]  train-auc:0.929360+0.004683 test-auc:0.867645+0.053280 
> >     [77]  train-auc:0.929817+0.004426 test-auc:0.868134+0.054196 
> >     [78]  train-auc:0.930156+0.004416 test-auc:0.867472+0.054034 
> >     [79]  train-auc:0.930336+0.004371 test-auc:0.867463+0.053932 
> >     [80]  train-auc:0.930774+0.004482 test-auc:0.867997+0.054005 
> >     [81]  train-auc:0.931103+0.004319 test-auc:0.867835+0.054027 
> >     [82]  train-auc:0.931436+0.004340 test-auc:0.867459+0.053907 
> >     [83]  train-auc:0.931650+0.004284 test-auc:0.866549+0.053899 
> >     [84]  train-auc:0.931984+0.004116 test-auc:0.866696+0.054119 
> >     [85]  train-auc:0.932413+0.004126 test-auc:0.866812+0.053876 
> >     [86]  train-auc:0.932853+0.004255 test-auc:0.866699+0.053729 
> >     [87]  train-auc:0.933132+0.004264 test-auc:0.866588+0.053681 
> >     [88]  train-auc:0.933688+0.004378 test-auc:0.866346+0.053490 
> >     [89]  train-auc:0.934066+0.004233 test-auc:0.866561+0.053246 
> >     [90]  train-auc:0.934529+0.004557 test-auc:0.866569+0.053029 
> >     [91]  train-auc:0.934796+0.004587 test-auc:0.866623+0.053103 
> >     [92]  train-auc:0.935168+0.004627 test-auc:0.865982+0.053365 
> >     [93]  train-auc:0.935630+0.004560 test-auc:0.865622+0.053572 
> >     [94]  train-auc:0.935930+0.004483 test-auc:0.865783+0.053594 
> >     [95]  train-auc:0.936319+0.004339 test-auc:0.865757+0.053474 
> >     [96]  train-auc:0.936615+0.004263 test-auc:0.865538+0.053517 
> >     [97]  train-auc:0.936840+0.004360 test-auc:0.865439+0.053619 
> >     [98]  train-auc:0.937240+0.004283 test-auc:0.865529+0.053559 
> >     [99]  train-auc:0.937612+0.004325 test-auc:0.865924+0.053515 
> >     [100] train-auc:0.937934+0.004419 test-auc:0.865869+0.053225 
> >     [101] train-auc:0.938170+0.004512 test-auc:0.865770+0.053696 
> >     [102] train-auc:0.938491+0.004540 test-auc:0.865449+0.053774 
> >     [103] train-auc:0.938744+0.004574 test-auc:0.865712+0.052924 
> >     [104] train-auc:0.938961+0.004587 test-auc:0.865698+0.052789 
> >     [105] train-auc:0.939429+0.004391 test-auc:0.866574+0.053548 
> >     [106] train-auc:0.939608+0.004285 test-auc:0.866846+0.053928 
> >     [107] train-auc:0.940049+0.004231 test-auc:0.866967+0.054383 
> >     [108] train-auc:0.940273+0.004230 test-auc:0.867415+0.054812 
> >     [109] train-auc:0.940599+0.004284 test-auc:0.866757+0.054485 
> >     [110] train-auc:0.940855+0.004281 test-auc:0.866719+0.054324 
> >     [111] train-auc:0.941248+0.004187 test-auc:0.866606+0.054411 
> >     [112] train-auc:0.941609+0.004178 test-auc:0.866776+0.054262 
> >     [113] train-auc:0.942016+0.004326 test-auc:0.867379+0.054235 
> >     [114] train-auc:0.942123+0.004331 test-auc:0.867263+0.054290 
> >     [115] train-auc:0.942362+0.004380 test-auc:0.867058+0.054484 
> >     [116] train-auc:0.942642+0.004397 test-auc:0.867212+0.053896 
> >     [117] train-auc:0.942910+0.004512 test-auc:0.866902+0.054213 
> >     [118] train-auc:0.943095+0.004524 test-auc:0.866685+0.053992 
> >     [119] train-auc:0.943411+0.004400 test-auc:0.866844+0.053564 
> >     [120] train-auc:0.943627+0.004282 test-auc:0.867069+0.054186 
> >     [121] train-auc:0.943793+0.004305 test-auc:0.867372+0.053924 
> >     [122] train-auc:0.944034+0.004300 test-auc:0.867482+0.053637 
> >     [123] train-auc:0.944404+0.004257 test-auc:0.867957+0.053311 
> >     [124] train-auc:0.944712+0.004312 test-auc:0.868072+0.053453 
> >     [125] train-auc:0.944997+0.004157 test-auc:0.869068+0.053413 
> >     [126] train-auc:0.945215+0.004118 test-auc:0.869093+0.053406 
> >     [127] train-auc:0.945473+0.004058 test-auc:0.869137+0.053200 
> >     [128] train-auc:0.945871+0.003948 test-auc:0.869462+0.053528 
> >     [129] train-auc:0.946026+0.003936 test-auc:0.869688+0.053372 
> >     [130] train-auc:0.946277+0.003754 test-auc:0.869576+0.053113 
> >     [131] train-auc:0.946444+0.003649 test-auc:0.869194+0.053095 
> >     [132] train-auc:0.946642+0.003725 test-auc:0.869515+0.052871 
> >     [133] train-auc:0.946820+0.003592 test-auc:0.869199+0.052938 
> >     [134] train-auc:0.947051+0.003620 test-auc:0.869311+0.052884 
> >     [135] train-auc:0.947473+0.003638 test-auc:0.870009+0.052410 
> >     [136] train-auc:0.947780+0.003629 test-auc:0.869906+0.052172 
> >     [137] train-auc:0.948068+0.003695 test-auc:0.869593+0.052137 
> >     [138] train-auc:0.948298+0.003800 test-auc:0.869807+0.051708 
> >     [139] train-auc:0.948461+0.003800 test-auc:0.869279+0.052147 
> >     [140] train-auc:0.948715+0.003760 test-auc:0.869389+0.052126 
> >     [141] train-auc:0.948981+0.003686 test-auc:0.869353+0.052317 
> >     [142] train-auc:0.949199+0.003648 test-auc:0.869630+0.052192 
> >     [143] train-auc:0.949387+0.003586 test-auc:0.869038+0.052386 
> >     [144] train-auc:0.949599+0.003620 test-auc:0.869290+0.052218 
> >     [145] train-auc:0.949904+0.003591 test-auc:0.869723+0.051909 
> >     [146] train-auc:0.950152+0.003542 test-auc:0.870094+0.052072 
> >     [147] train-auc:0.950349+0.003444 test-auc:0.869605+0.051703 
> >     [148] train-auc:0.950581+0.003447 test-auc:0.869659+0.051793 
> >     [149] train-auc:0.950802+0.003429 test-auc:0.869284+0.051968 
> >     [150] train-auc:0.951045+0.003509 test-auc:0.868943+0.052391 
> >     [151] train-auc:0.951256+0.003528 test-auc:0.869113+0.052452 
> >     [152] train-auc:0.951533+0.003455 test-auc:0.869608+0.051146 
> >     [153] train-auc:0.951776+0.003452 test-auc:0.869464+0.051480 
> >     [154] train-auc:0.952069+0.003511 test-auc:0.869697+0.050773 
> >     [155] train-auc:0.952243+0.003447 test-auc:0.869850+0.050781 
> >     [156] train-auc:0.952522+0.003466 test-auc:0.869631+0.051013 
> >     [157] train-auc:0.952750+0.003430 test-auc:0.868954+0.051264 
> >     [158] train-auc:0.952986+0.003302 test-auc:0.868899+0.050795 
> >     [159] train-auc:0.953262+0.003318 test-auc:0.869263+0.050704 
> >     [160] train-auc:0.953457+0.003253 test-auc:0.869479+0.050793 
> >     [161] train-auc:0.953652+0.003300 test-auc:0.869534+0.050539 
> >     [162] train-auc:0.954006+0.003246 test-auc:0.869209+0.050546 
> >     [163] train-auc:0.954325+0.003080 test-auc:0.869472+0.050937 
> >     [164] train-auc:0.954566+0.003039 test-auc:0.869787+0.051283 
> >     [165] train-auc:0.954751+0.003020 test-auc:0.870019+0.051601 
> >     [166] train-auc:0.954947+0.003063 test-auc:0.869687+0.051775 
> >     [167] train-auc:0.955228+0.003122 test-auc:0.869682+0.051919 
> >     [168] train-auc:0.955369+0.003181 test-auc:0.869351+0.051832 
> >     [169] train-auc:0.955590+0.003116 test-auc:0.869254+0.051729 
> >     [170] train-auc:0.955800+0.003130 test-auc:0.868659+0.052226 
> >     [171] train-auc:0.955973+0.003165 test-auc:0.868595+0.052111 
> >     [172] train-auc:0.956239+0.003307 test-auc:0.868854+0.051982 
> >     [173] train-auc:0.956409+0.003291 test-auc:0.869171+0.051843 
> >     [174] train-auc:0.956584+0.003241 test-auc:0.869083+0.052108 
> >     [175] train-auc:0.956735+0.003290 test-auc:0.869097+0.052149 
> >     [176] train-auc:0.957047+0.003332 test-auc:0.869146+0.052037 
> >     [177] train-auc:0.957270+0.003337 test-auc:0.869041+0.052098 
> >     [178] train-auc:0.957416+0.003358 test-auc:0.869358+0.052262 
> >     [179] train-auc:0.957657+0.003385 test-auc:0.869679+0.051461 
> >     [180] train-auc:0.957852+0.003407 test-auc:0.869796+0.051852 
> >     [181] train-auc:0.957961+0.003399 test-auc:0.870012+0.052018 
> >     [182] train-auc:0.958129+0.003470 test-auc:0.869848+0.053008 
> >     [183] train-auc:0.958341+0.003455 test-auc:0.870424+0.052901 
> >     [184] train-auc:0.958481+0.003462 test-auc:0.870379+0.053007 
> >     [185] train-auc:0.958621+0.003487 test-auc:0.869798+0.053354 
> >     [186] train-auc:0.958754+0.003481 test-auc:0.869790+0.052790 
> >     [187] train-auc:0.958929+0.003489 test-auc:0.869948+0.052531 
> >     [188] train-auc:0.959051+0.003485 test-auc:0.869826+0.052705 
> >     [189] train-auc:0.959154+0.003557 test-auc:0.869825+0.052674 
> >     [190] train-auc:0.959389+0.003488 test-auc:0.869134+0.052981 
> >     [191] train-auc:0.959640+0.003534 test-auc:0.869139+0.052928 
> >     [192] train-auc:0.959802+0.003548 test-auc:0.868721+0.053014 
> >     [193] train-auc:0.959943+0.003554 test-auc:0.868621+0.053073 
> >     [194] train-auc:0.960091+0.003548 test-auc:0.868896+0.053038 
> >     [195] train-auc:0.960262+0.003518 test-auc:0.868815+0.053007 
> >     [196] train-auc:0.960446+0.003483 test-auc:0.868435+0.053389 
> >     [197] train-auc:0.960651+0.003504 test-auc:0.868740+0.052869 
> >     [198] train-auc:0.960811+0.003404 test-auc:0.868526+0.052753 
> >     [199] train-auc:0.961005+0.003476 test-auc:0.868301+0.052774 
> >     [200] train-auc:0.961263+0.003473 test-auc:0.869224+0.052641  Warning
> >     message: In xgb.get.DMatrix(data, label, missing) : xgboost: label
> >     will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general (regardless of specific algorithm you use), the approach to detecting overfitting is as follows:

1) Split data set into train and test set (say 90% - train, 10% - test dataset).

2) Train the classifier on train dataset for some number of iterations (or using some value of hyperparameters, if you try to tweak various parameter values instead of several iterations of training)

3) Try to use the trained classifier against test dataset and calculate how accurate is it (F1 metric, or AUC or just Accuracy if you prefer).

4) Repeat 3-4 untill your metric from #3 starts to decrease vs previous step.

In your case you don't split dataset into train and test - thus I think it is impossible to detect if you actually overfit or no.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I got what you are trying to say.

Comment: I divided the training set into 90 train and 10 validate set. I used the same xgb model as above with a few parameters tweaked, predicted on the validate set and calculated the **F1 score and got 0.862069**